# Check in Jest unit tests that returned brushX or brushY

Tags: d3.js, jestjs, ts-jest

Is it possible to detect in unit tests that we have `d3.brushX()` or `d3.brushY()` object?

Even check like:

```
expect(JSON.stringify(d3.brushY())).toBe(JSON.stringify(d3.brushX()));
```

Do you know any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
expect(d3.brushY() || d3.brushX()).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: But still, we don't know that this is X or Y - we can just be sure that this is `d3.brush`